# git add solicits an error

Tags: git, repository

Windows 7, Visual Studio, Git newbie

A repository was created and initialized here: A:\Git_Repository
 The working directory is: E:\CODE\Common_Code.
 A command line window is started and the default directory set to the working directory. The following command is entered

git add * A:\Git_Repository

The response was that this is not a repository. Of course it is not a repository, It is my working directory! I certainly don't want my repository inside the working directory where I do all my work. I don't even want it on the same hard drive.

What is the procedure or step to add all the files in the working directory here: E:\CODE\Common_Code to the repository here: A:\Git_Repository

Answer (score 0):

You could create a symlink to the .git directory from your working directory by running in E:\CODE\Common_Code

```
mklink /j .git A:\Git_Repository\.git
```